# Why so many [not cacheable] files with webpack recompile?

Tags: typescript, webpack

I have a fairly small project. Around 800 modules. When I change one of the files, and the webpack-watch recompiles everything, it takes much longer than I would like. And I think that the main reason is that when it is done, it lists hundreds of files that are `[not cacheable]`.

[image]

There are hundreds of these files each time I save even a single-char change.

Any ideas on what could be causing these files to be not cacheable? Any ideas on where I can start looking to figure it out? I have poked around and been unsuccessful so far. The only loader for my `.js` files is `ts-loader`. Other than that, I don't use other loaders.

I just need some ideas on where to start. [This github issue](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/748) has been around for years, with no answer on it. People need help figuring out how to know why a certain file isn't cacheable. Any ideas here would be much appreciated. I can show samples from my `webpack.config.js`. I am on webpack 1 for now. I don't think that is the issue.

Let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have an answer that will solve this for everyone. But, for my case, I was using a loader that made my stuff not-cacheable. Once I fixed that, I was good to go. The loader I was using is [mark-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mark-loader). Once I took that out, all the files were immediately cacheable again.